# take and upload picture using Mirror API for Glass

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

while it's possible to send image to glass in a timeline card, it doesn't look like it's possible to to the opposite (take a picture and upload it).

If I'm correct, this operation would be performed as a user action in the mirror APIs (like SHARE, REPLY, NAVIGATE), but I don't see any camera related function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you can't add a user action to take a photo directly from one of your timeline cards, you can register a `Contact` and `Subscription` to receive photos.

When the user takes a photo using the normal camera function of Glass, they can then `SHARE` the photo with your `Contact` and you will get a notification at the endpoint you specified in the `Subscription`.

See the following URLs as reference:

- https://developers.google.com/glass/contacts#how_sharing_works
- https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#shared_picture